# MongoDB count and regex search count not matching

Tags: regex, mongodb, pcre, database

I have a huge mongoDB containing documents on which I am using a name as index.

So basically, I had a text file containing 48 000 016 entries. (I use wc -l to obtain that count)

To give more context, the database contains a lot of names that we're extracted from OCR (so a lot of junk) and also names in other languages (Japanese, Russian, etc...).

My MongoDB table statistics tell me I have 48 000 016 which is fine.

The problem happens because I want to query the items on their names (which is a standard string) using this regex :

```
 /^([A-Z]|\W|\s|\d|_)/i
```

So my checklist :

- any letter - check
- case insensitive - check
- any number - check
- underscore - check
- \W for anything that is not a number, letter or underscore.

So from what I understand, this regex should get me everything, since I am querying database on string values with this regex. But the problem is that I am missing 5 items.

When I run the count on the result of the query, I have 48 000 011 items.

Any idea where these 5 ones could be ? Because of the nature of my problem I can simply go through all my items using a simple cursor, I know it could be done that way, but I need a regex that can retrieve all my values.

I ran this query on the Database as indicated by the comments.

```
db.name.aggregate({$group:{_id:"uniqueDocs", count:{$sum:1}}})
```

Result is :

```
{ "result" : [ ], "ok" : 1 }
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: How about to inverse the regex and check the results?

Comment: Please use run `db.<insertYourCollectionNameHere>.aggregate({$group:{_id:"uniqueDocs",count:{$sum:1}}})` and add this to your question [by editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38559714/edit)

Comment: Try to include `\n\r`to your regex, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank @Paul Wasilewski for giving me some great solutions. I found my problem which was not related to a regex problem.

My 5 entries we're simply not indexed, their size was more than 1024 bytes in length so MongoDB could not index them.

So that's the reason why they could not be queried by regex.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen you are using the anchor `^` to match the beginnig of a line. It could be possible that the line start with an new line `\n` or carriage return character `\r`.

Try to include `\n` and `\r` to your regex

```
/^([A-Z]|\W|\s|\d|\r|\n|_)/i
```

Also check to remove the anchor.

```
/([A-Z]|\W|\s|\d|\r|\n|_)/i
```

At last option inverse your regex to see which records are not included. These regex expressions should also math empty strings.

```
/^(?![.*])/i
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question, the regex I showed is the compact version, in reality I am using something like this  : A|B|C|D... that I generate from a python array because I want to process the database in multiple concurrent processes. I double check and there's no error in these. They correctly give me the same result as the posted regex. So the problem  lies elsewhere.

Comment: I tried both commands, it still give me the same results. From what I can read, \W should match on everything else, but it's not. So my guess is that I have empty strings or special characters that cannot be processed by regex. Is that possible ?

Comment: @ElCapitaine, empty strings could be a good explanation. Try to inverse the regex ^(?![.*]) and take a look at the results. This should also find empty strings